# Task process only sending e-mail to one approver

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I created a task process with two participants, however, only one participant receives an e-mail to approve the task. The approval process is parallel (all are supposed to receive a task at once). Even when I go to the task list only one of the users has been assigned to the task of approving a document.

I am working with out of the box workflows in SPD 2013. These are also 2013 workflows.

Comment: dose the other user have a valid email?

Comment: If you are using a workflow to send to the 2 users in parallel are you manually entering a text email address in the to field or are you selecting the user? If selecting the user, then be sure that the User Information List on the SITE has a good address for the user who is not getting an email. You may need to have that user visit that site to trigger the population of the User Information list.